# Phone stuck in sideload mode

Tags: adb, samsung, side-loading

I am trying to flash stock rom with magdisk, and after executing `./adb reboot sideload`, i tried `./adb sideload file.zip`. however, it showed

```
adb: sideload connection failed: no devices/emulators found
adb: trying pre-KitKat sideload method...
adb: pre-KitKat sideload connection failed: no devices/emulators found
```

now, I cannot get into regular boot. after hard resetting(holding all buttons), it just reboots... into sideload mode. I tried waiting a day, but nothing happend. I have a samsung galaxy a14. SM-A145R, with EUX region code.

Comment: Samsung phones are usually flashed using Odin/Heimdall, nut sure if they support sideloading an ROM via adb at all.

Answer (score -2):

To me it sounds like you soft-bricked your device, I think you'll have to either do recovery through your recovery system (if you can get to it) or factory reset

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i can't get to it, as already told. im stuck in sideload. i cant factory reset.